# Why C doesn't throw any warning when the char * is returned?

Tags: c

Here is the code that has a function GetString, this returns a char pointer.
This char pointer is pointing to the string, which is in the stack.
Now, why does the C compiler doesn't throw any warning when the address is returned for that string? Is the scope limited? Is it really a problem?
Is "Hello" stored in Data Segment?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    char * GetString()
    {
       char *Hello = "Hello";

      return Hello;

    }

    int main(void)
    {
      printf("%s",GetString());
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't rely on the possibility that the compiler will warn you about a particular piece of code, rather you should learn the rules and pitfalls of the language.

Comment: The code is in fact valid, that's why you don't get a warning.  Don't hesitate to change the function return type to const char*, that you don't have to is the real problem.  Not enough courage back in 1989.

Answer (score 5):

```
char* GetString() 
{ 
    char Hello[] = "Hello"; 
    return Hello; 
}
```

would return a pointer to a stack allocated string.

```
char* GetString() 
{ 
    char* Hello = "Hello"; 
    return Hello; 
}
```

returns a pointer to a static string. (And you should really make it a `char const*` pointer because string literals are effectively (but not formally) const).

Even if you wrote

```
char* GetString() 
{ 
    char Hello[] = "Hello"; 
    return Hello; 
}
```

however, the compiler is under no obligation to warn you about this. C is not Rust.

Comment: But some compiler *can* warn about it given the right flags. I.e., you have to ask your compiler for it (if it is supported).

Comment: @BoR Indeed, gcc and clang with default settings do warn if you're returning a pointer to a local: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VQ5Hds